# <%= debug(controller) %> produces unreadable output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

In one of my templates I want to take a closer look at the controller object using the debug() helper.

It is said to produce YAML suitable for HTML output.

Running <%= debug(controller) %> does, however, not produce anything I call readable.

It begins with:

```
#<ClubsController:0x104467378 @_request=#<ActionController::Request:0x104467648 @accepts=[#<Mime::Type:0x101f50f30 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"],
```

and goes on like that...

Any ideas on how to get some info about the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `debug` helper is primarily intended to be used with objects that provide an implementation of `to_yaml` (such as ActiveRecord models). If the object passed doesn't respond to `to_yaml` (as is the case with passing a controller object in your example) then `debug` gives you the result from calling `inspect` on that object.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your comment @thenduks answer.

Actually there is a method:

```
controller.controller_name
```

that returns the name of the controller.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Just found the page in the documentation about it too.

Answer (score 0):

What's not readable about that? It's the standard ruby inspection syntax... If you really need something 'more readable' then you'll have to write a method on your controller (temporarily, most likely) that simply exposes it's instance variables in another format.

Perhaps it would help if you noted *what* you want to see in the controller instance.

Comment: I wanted to display the current controller name alongside the action name. The action name is available in controller.action_name so I thought I could use debug() to see if I could find a attribute in controller that held the name.

Comment: So what's the problem? Look through that output (or better yet, through the ActionController docs) for the right method names and just do `<%= controller.controller_name %>` and `<%= controller.action_name %>` or whatever they end up being.